# Appearance -> Menus doesn't show

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu, theme-options

Ony of my colleges started with the implementation of a new theme, 
I'm trying to add Menus but the option doesn't show.

anyone know how to bring that back? thx.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add following code into your theme **functions.php** file

```
function pietergoosen_theme_setup() {
  register_nav_menus( array( 
    'header' => 'Header menu', 
    'footer' => 'Footer menu' 
  ) );
 }

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'pietergoosen_theme_setup' );
```

Please check at your end and let me know if any query.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: If this answer is useful for you then please you can accept this answer.